# With wrk, what is the most efficient way to do a HTTP PUT with a file as a body?

Tags: http, lua, put, wrk

I want to benchmark an application by doing many HTTP PUT request that include files body. I have many files and each file need to be sent only one time.

For now I am trying to do that using WRK. One way i have find to do that is to split my data in several repo, giving each WRK thread a repo. But my big problem is how to pass the file as a PUT parameter (basically do a curl -T). For now i am doing it by reding the file in the LUA script and puting the content into wrk.body which is not very performant (too slow).

Here is the part of code i am using to do the PUT with a file parameter :

```
function read_file(path)
  local file, errorMessage = io.open(path, "r")
  if not file then 
    error("Could not read the file: "..path.." Error : " .. errorMessage .. "\n")
  end

  local content = file:read "*all"
  file:close()
  return content
end

request = function()
  local body = read_file("/data/"..id.."/"..files[counter])
  counter = counter + 1
  local Boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundaryePkpFF7tjBAqx29L"
  wrk.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" .. Boundary

  return wrk.format("PUT", url, wrk.headers,body)
end
```

I just want to know if there is a more efficient way to add a file as a PUT (or POST) HTTP request using WRK.

Comment: Please include a code example of what you have attempted.

Comment: I add some code example. I remove all the code that array the list of the files names, thread id etc but some variables are still present.